# C Program with Stack that have int and char

Tags: c

I have a homework assignment to do, and the question goes on like this :
Receive from the user up to 20 integers and push them into a stack(static stack), by pressing 'o' on the keyboard, the stack pop the numbers in reverse order.
Hint(from my teacher): pop out the numbers one by one from the stack.

My problem is that this program is printing reverse of the input **with 'o'**.
And if I input a two digit number it's printing him in reverse order too. for example: 67 ---> 76.

I tried everything I know so far, even ask 2nd-year students for help which they couldn't provide. so I'm here to check what is wrong with my code.

My Main :

```
int i , x = 0 ,count = 0; 
    stack s1;
    stack_init(&s1);

    printf("Please enter numbers: \n");
    scanf_s("%c", &x);
    while(x != 'o' )
    {
        scanf_s("%c", &x);
        stack_push(&s1, x);
        count++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", stack_pop(&s1));
    }
```

Comment: why are you treating integer as `char`s?

Comment: In almost every case `char` can be treated as integers, *except* when passing pointers (using e.g. the address-of operator `&`). The type `int *` is *very* different from `char *`. Mismatching `scanf` format specifier and argument type (like using `"%c"` and passing `int *`) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You should be getting numerous compiler warnings. Read them, fix them.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is the order of operations: you *always* push the input onto the stack immediately after reading it. Only afterwards do you test whether the user entered `'o'`. Reverse the order of your operations inside the loop to fix this:

```
for (;;) {
    // read input
    // test if input is "o" and exit loop
    // convert input to number and push onto stack.
}
```

Additionally, I suggest reading *strings*, not characters, from the input. That way the user can correctly enter multi-digit numbers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Ok , will do that right away.

Comment: Hey, I've tried to do so. no success, mind to write an example for me that I can study from it?